Can I setup multiple fluentd configurations in one fluentd installation?
I want to create multiple pipelines for datastreams that use fluentd. For example, if I have a data stream that comes from kafka, I want to use some filters and then finally send the data to elastic search. Now, I may have multiple data streams like this or even different types of sources like log files, or GCP Pub/Sub.
To do this for a single source, I can create a config file with the relevant details but is it possible to have multiple config files and then a global config file which tells fluentd where all the config files are?
The other way to do this is to create a new fluentd instance each time I want to use a different source but this would be too costly and I dont think is ideal.
I have tried going through their documentation but only find resources to create a single config file.

Yes, it is possible. You just have to create master config file like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-logging
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: fluentd
data: 
  fluent.conf: |
    <system>
      log_level warn
    </system>

    <label @FLUENT_LOG>
      <match fluent.**>
        @type loki
        url "http://loki:3100"
        <buffer>
          flush_interval 10s
          flush_at_shutdown true
        </buffer>
        extra_labels {"job":"fluentd_internal", "component":"logging", "host":"unknown"}
      </match>
    </label>

    @include conf.d/*.conf

    <match **>
      @type loki
      url "http://loki:3100"
      <buffer>
        flush_interval 10s
        flush_at_shutdown true
      </buffer>
      extra_labels {"job":"unknown", "component":"unknown", "host":"unknown", "agent":"unknown"}
    </match>

You need to note 2 things: @include directive and that it is coming before global <match>.

Yes, you can use the include directive within the config file. However, be mindful that using @include is tricky; adding files in the incorrect order could completely break your Fluentd configuration. Therefore, if you have a directory of files to add,
@include conf.d/*.conf

Will include all files in alfabetic order.It's advisable to add all the files you will use in a sequential order, as follows:
# If you have a.conf, b.conf, ..., z.conf and a.conf / z.conf are important

# This is bad
@include *.conf

# This is good
@include a.conf
@include config.d/*.conf
@include z.conf

Documentation on this subject is accessible here: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#id-7.-reuse-your-config-the-include-directive
